# Stock Charts in wxFormbuilder/Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, wxformbuilder

I have my application below in wxFormbuilder: 
[image]

In the area highlighted with the red border, I would like to be able to present a stock chart there. I understand the matplotlib import can handle stock charts, but how can I bind that chart to the gray panel in my app?

Comment: you should really just manually build your layouts imho with subclasses and whatnot ... I have found the vast majority of the gui layout design things to be way more hassle than they are worth ... (unfortunately that doesnt help you much with your issue ...)

Comment: http://s231426.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/wxformbuilder_python/ may be helpful to you